# How to change the 'X' button in a jquery dialog box to read 'Close'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog

I had a jquery dialog box in an MVC razor-view with a close button inside it. But on clicking the close button, the dialog just got **hidden** and **not removed**, so that when a click on any link on the page it doesnt work, which is not desired; noe do i want to redirect to my action method every time  i close the dialog.

On clicking the 'X' button on the dialog-header, i get exactly what i want. So my senior now wants me to completely remove the 'Close' button and write "close" instead of 'X' in the header. I managed to do it editing my dialogbox thru my chrome browser console, on removing a **whole lot of CSS class** that the dialog-header uses. 
      But i cannot figure out fwhere to change the code(CSS or jquery) in my project in order to make this happen!! Please enlighten me about dialogboxes!!

here is my dialogbox:

```
$(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $(".ExportStatus").live("click", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var height = 350, width = 370;  //height = 350 width = 345; 
            $('<div><span class="well"  style="position: absolute; top: 85px; left: 70px"><img src="' + loaderimagePath + '" alt="Processing your request. Please wait..." /></span></div>')
            .addClass("dialog")
            .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
            .appendTo("body")
            .dialog({
                //                    open: function () {
                //                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").val() = closebutton;
                //                    },
                title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                closeOnEscape: true,
                resizable: false,
                //                    close: $(this).attr("data-dialog-titlebar-close"),         
                //                      $("data-dialog-title-close").live("click", 
                //                    function () {
                //                        $(".ui-dialog").hide();
                //                        $(".ui-widget-overlay").hide();
                //                    },                       
                //window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 0);   $(this).remove()
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(".ui-dialog").remove();
                        $(".ui-widget-overlay").remove();
                        // $(" #quickfillDialog").dialog("hide");

                        return false;
                    }


                },![enter image description here][1]
                modal: true,
                position: 'middle',
                width: width,
                height: height
            })

            // $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click( function() {
            // $(this).parent().children().children("a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();
            .load(this.href, function (response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    $('.dialog').html(msg + xhr.status + "<br/>" + xhr.statusText + "<br/>" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the dialog part of the jQuery code above as:

```
.dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')
            .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
            .html('<span style="float:right;">Close</span>');
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That works just perfect!!! Thanks a lot Palash!!! :) 
Just wondering if u can help me put the "ui-state-hover" class in place for the button!

Comment: by default the <span> had class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick", and the <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all"> & "ui-state-hover"(on-hover)which highlighted the 'X' button on hover and a box appeared  on bckground

Comment: by ading and removing classes from the browser console i found that on setting the <a style="float:right" class=""> i get what i want(ie. the highlight-box in the background of the button) but not by <span style="float:right">

Comment: So how can i add **style="float:right"** to the <a>. The <a> for the close button is in-built in the **"dialog"** class i guess..

Comment: `open: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')
            .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
            .css('float','right')
            .html('Close');
    }`

Comment: U r great man!! \m/ That too worked just fine... 8)  it's frustrating working with CSS in jquery! i cud have never got that myself... Thanks a Lot again!

Answer (score 0):

This Works.

Create a custom CSS.

```
.ui-dialogpopupclose {
      visibility: hidden;
}
```

Use below code to Add / Remove in your Dialog Box.

```
open: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").addClass('ui-dialogpopupclose');
},
close: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").removeClass('ui-dialogpopupclose');
}
```