# Jquery tooltip on dialog close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tooltip

In a web application that I am working on I have partial view that I display on a "details" page via a JqueryUI Dialog box. I am trying to add a JqueryUI tooltip for the close button, in the top right corner of the header, that comes stock with the dialog box. Below I have some of my code. I know the scripts will work from the location they are at currently in this web application due to my second function below. '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close' is the class that is applied to the close button in the dialog header (based off chrome firebug). The closest answer I've found to the solution was here https://forum.jquery.com/topic/tooltip-in-a-dialog-pop-up-without-hovering

Found this question similar to mine...
[How to change the 'X' button in a jquery dialog box to read 'Close'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451994/how-to-change-the-x-button-in-a-jquery-dialog-box-to-read-close?rq=1)
...any way I could manipulate the close button achieve what I asked like this? For example a ".addTitle()"?? About to tinker with this idea.

Any and all help or information is appreciated.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').tooltip({
        content: function () {
            return "test";
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#testThing').tooltip();
});

</script>
```

With many thanks,
Rock

Answer (score 2):

I would try using the create event on your dialog:

```
$("yourSelector").dialog({
   create: function(){$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").attr("title","Your text goes here");}
});
```

Comment: Ended up being a style sheet thing overwriting my intended style. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by editing line which has

```
.addClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all")
```

in 'jquery.ui.dialog.js' or ('jquery.ui.all.js') page,  It currently reads

```
.attr('role', 'button')
```

simply change it to

```
.attr({'role': 'button', 'title': "close (Esc)")
```

this will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to update the options configuration of jQuery UI dialog. Like:

```
$("#dialogConfirm").dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    modal : true,
    resizable : false,
    dialogClass : "confirm-dialog",
    closeText : "Click to Close the dialog" // Here is the Gem
});
```